Gaussian 16 input error when using the Gen option, and when using geom=allcheck
Good time of day!
As I think I have the following problem with Gen option in TD-DFT computations in Gaussian 16. I provided optimization with the following input successfully.
    %mem=16GB
    %nprocshared=8
    %chk=TaOCl.chk
    #B3LYP/Gen pseudo=read opt freq IOp(5/13=1) scf=(XQC,maxcyc=40) POP=(Full)
    
    Taocl
    
    0 1
     Ta                 0.52441600    2.34088700    0.27677200
     Ta                 2.25547600   -0.89148600   -0.17657400
     Ta                -1.51660800   -0.79140200   -0.11232400
     Ta                -1.56498800   -0.70926600   -3.82585600
     Ta                 2.05063700   -1.05491100   -3.90272100
     Ta                 0.28802700    2.24318300   -3.43176100
     O                  0.38175800   -1.24689900   -0.37045500
     O                 -0.87456000    0.92921800    0.24172100
     O                  1.70524900    0.84377000    0.40072200
     O                 -1.83584600   -1.09840800   -1.96674500
     O                  2.47226500   -1.13386100   -2.06700100
     O                  0.27637900    2.72359100   -1.53385600
     O                  0.20883400   -1.32121700   -4.29847200
     O                 -1.26067000    1.18939300   -3.90064900
     O                  1.55282700    0.85387600   -3.64268600
     O                  0.57375300    3.56623700   -4.52700100
     O                 -2.82891400   -1.27449000   -4.88038900
     Cl                -3.75309600   -0.17606800    0.26157100
     Cl                 2.30574100    3.80314600    0.62349600
     Cl                 2.51945000   -3.31890200   -4.20989800
     Cl                -0.78163200    3.44686700    1.83500500
     Cl                 3.59682600   -0.40800800   -5.48359700
     Cl                -1.60607800   -2.41472100    1.54034100
     Cl                 2.49629300   -2.62106000    1.32021700
     Cl                 4.51800000   -0.25984600    0.01703900 
    
    Cl 0
    6-31G(d)
    ****
    Ta O 0
    LANL2DZ
    ****
    
    Ta O 0
    LANL2DZ
    
    END
    ech "Job done. "

After that I tried to provide TD-DFT computations with the following input file.
%mem=30GB
%nprocshared=4
%chk=TaOCl.chk
#p B3LYP/gen td(NStates=16) pseudo=read guess=read geom=allcheck Iop(9/40=2)

TaOCl

0 1
Ta        2.489911    0.339824    1.533423
Ta        0.644364    2.199516   -1.075488
Ta        1.558530   -1.417192   -1.654731
Ta       -1.831306   -2.428608   -0.517265
Ta       -2.792369    1.055915   -0.172163
Ta       -0.902052   -0.850113    2.472752
O         0.763463    0.386494   -1.679255
O         2.294218   -0.888848   -0.023104
O         1.865335    1.643895    0.294037
O        -0.186405   -2.164680   -1.464721
O        -1.216888    1.948083   -0.710991
O         1.004560   -0.418521    2.377256
O        -2.849493   -0.784149   -0.640637
O        -1.351115   -2.352502    1.344063
O        -1.810855    0.454405    1.449025
O        -1.548205   -0.988173    4.083583
O        -2.711188   -3.859848   -0.971468
Cl        2.563105   -3.539771   -1.589753
Cl        2.884456    1.987687    3.133109
Cl       -3.915430    1.677480   -2.119135
Cl        4.585710   -0.586852    1.858899
Cl       -4.375237    2.037316    1.183815
Cl        2.603091   -0.898812   -3.659296
Cl        1.359960    2.998732   -3.109639
Cl        0.575278    4.355917   -0.126169

Cl 0
6-31G(d)
****
Ta O 0
LANL2DZ
****

Ta O 0
LANL2DZ

END
ech "Job done. "

I have obtained the following error in the log file
 General basis read from cards:  (5D, 7F)
 Unrecognized atomic symbolTaOCl

How to correct this problem there? What I need to do. Also I know the following solution using this input then the problem is solved. In this case program just read all information from chk file.
%mem=30GB
%nprocshared=6
%chk=TaOCl.chk
#p Geom=AllCheck ChkBas Guess=(Read,Only) td(NStates=20) Iop(9/40=2)

What is the problem with input with Gen there? What need I add above in the previous input file for running program with the gen option?
Thank you!

You've specified both geom=allcheck (meaning the geometry and other variables should be read from the checkpoint file), and have included the geometry again in the input file.
With geom=allcheck, Gaussian doesn't expect to find the title line ("TaOCl" in your case), charge/multiplicity, or geometry, so it jumps straight to reading the general basis set information. Because you have accidentally included the title section, Gaussian tries to parse "TaOCl" as part of a basis set, hence the rather cryptic error: "Unrecognized atomic symbolTaOCl".
Remove the title and geometry, so your input file looks like this:
%mem=30GB
%nprocshared=4
%chk=TaOCl.chk
#p B3LYP/gen td(NStates=16) pseudo=read guess=read geom=allcheck Iop(9/40=2)

Cl 0
6-31G(d)
****
Ta O 0
LANL2DZ
****

Ta O 0
LANL2DZ

END
ech "Job done. "

And all should be well.
Additionally, if you're already reading start information from the checkpoint file and don't plan on changing the basis set, you can use ChkBasis instead of Gen and pseudo=read to simply reuse the basis set info from the checkpoint file:
%mem=30GB
%nprocshared=4
%chk=TaOCl.chk
#p B3LYP/ChkBasis td(NStates=16) guess=read geom=allcheck Iop(9/40=2)

END
ech "Job done. "

PS. I've never seen END or ech given as part of a Gaussian input file before, if those are undocumented features I'd be cautious about using them.
